# How to redirect to a domain using Forge with DigitalOcean?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

Yesterday I made a host using Forge for Laravel application and I bought a domain from namecheap but from DigitalOcean I can't seem to redirect to the domain provided by namecheap.

In the DigitalOcean control panel I made a new domain and in the A section I set that @ to redirect to the IP address provided by Forge.

Answer (score 1):

Your DNS (at NameCheap Control Panel) should be pointed at the created DigitalOcean server IP address. The IP address is visible inside Laravel Forge and DigitalOcean.

Comment: I did it. Now in a Chromium browser I get the error 
"This page isn’t working [site.site] redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies."
and in Firefox I get the error
"Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies."

Comment: I have the same issue, i set a Custom DNS on namecheap under Domains, like "ns1.digitalocean.com" 2 and 3. Then on DigitalOcean under the green button "Create+/Domains" i entered a hostname like "mysite.com" and then for the value I used the droplet on this project. Which is what Forge is using and how i am linking my github repo to something on the internet. I've only done this so i still need to wait 48 hours according to Namecheap for it to take effect. Is this correct? Thank you.